# opengl drawing and moving primitive shapes

Tags: c++, opengl

So I'm venturing into openGL and to learn I'm drawing shapes. So I have the following code that draws  a polygon and it works as it should. I have two problems 1. if I comment out  `glTranslatef` it works,  but if I leave it it shows nothing. I understand `glTranslatef` is for movement so because there is no shape does that mean its moved away? If that is the case how do i make it move but come back so that I can see the same?

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-4.0f);

glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(-0.2f,0.2f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.2f,0.2f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.6f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.2f,-0.2f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.2f,-0.2f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.6f,0.0f,0.0f);
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's what you're missing:

The viewport extends from [-1,1] in all directions in the coordinate space you're working in (Normalized Device Coordinates). The z-axis is such that +z points straight ahead and -z points backwards with **-1.0** representing the nearest point you can see (near plane).

By translating everything **-4** units from **0**, you have moved your polygon **3** units **behind** you on the Z-axis. This will work fine as long as you restrict your translation to within +/- **1.0** unit on the z-axis, but you have gone well beyond that.

However, be aware that since you are not using perspective projection you really are not going to see any visual difference in this polygon as it moves away from you or closer (size will not change with distance). It will simply vanish once you move it far enough away (outside the range [-1,1]).

---

Most of the time, NDC is not a particularly useful coordinate space so you would use a non-identity ModelView and Projection matrix to define a larger and more controlled viewing volume. For the time being though, you are working in NDC because you have identity matrices.